# Aspect is not being triggered in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am developing an application with Spring Boot which I want it to have all the logging going through Aspects but I am not able to make it work.
I set 2 methods with `@AfterThrowing` and `@Before`, this last one as testing. The pointcuts are inspecting the packages of Controller, Services and Repositories.
The issue is that neither the log nor the `System.out.println()` is being shown in the console.

I have tried the different solutions I have seen here but none of them worked for me. I have the right dependencies, no further configuration is needed because it is already done with Spring Boot and I even tried to  use the poincuts with the annotations of the classes.

This is my package hierarchy

[image: Packages]

**Spring dependecies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**LoggingAspect**

```
package com.tlc.tracker.global.logging;

import com.tlc.tracker.global.exception.BusinessServiceException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;

@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(* com.tlc.tracker.v01.controller.*.*(..))")
public void controllerMethods() { }

@Pointcut("execution(* com.tlc.tracker.v01.service.imp.ProjectServiceImpl.*(..))")
public void serviceMethods(){  }

@Pointcut("execution(* com.tlc.tracker.v01.repository.*.*(..))")
public void respositoryMethods(){  }

@Before("serviceMethods()")
public void Areturn(JoinPoint point){
    System.out.println("Hola");
    log.info("HOLA");
}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "controllerMethods() && serviceMethods() && respositoryMethods()", throwing = "exception")
public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable exception){

    if(exception instanceof BusinessServiceException){
        //Get the parts of the exception message
        String exceptions[] = exception.getMessage().split(":", 2);
        //Get the message contained in the exception message
        String message = exceptions.length == 1 ? "" : exceptions[1];

        log.error("[" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "] - Type: " + exceptions[0] + ". Message: "+ message);
    }

    if(exception instanceof Exception){
        log.error("[" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "] - Type: ServerError. Message: "  + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

**ProjectController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v01")
@Slf4j
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectServiceIface projectService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/project", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Project> createProject(@Valid @RequestBody Project project, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            throw new BusinessServiceException(result.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage(), result.getFieldError().getField() + " " + result.getFieldError().getCode());
        }
        Project projectSaved = projectService.createProject(project);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Location", projectSaved.getId().toString());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(project, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**ProjectService**

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectServiceIface {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Override
    public Project createProject(Project project) {
        Project projectFound = projectRepository.findByName(project.getName());
        if(projectFound == null){
            throw new BusinessServiceException(Constants.FUNCTIONAL_ERROR, "The Project already exists");
        }
        project.setCreateTime(new Date());

        Project projectSaved = projectRepository.save(project);
        return projectSaved;
    }
}
```

**ProjectRepository**

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Project p WHERE p.name = :projectName", nativeQuery = true)
    public Project findByName(String projectName);
}
```

Comment: Use `||` instead of `&&` between your named pointcuts, and make sure you have enabled Spring AOP using `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`.

Comment: That does not work. Because the method with the ````@Before``` doesn't use the operators and it is not triggered either. Regarding ```@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)``` it is already included by default with Spring Boot so there is not need to write it.

Comment: Could you try adding `@Component` to your `LoggingAspect` class? My guess is that your `LoggingAspect` class is not picked up during component scanning as it is not explicitly declared in JavaConfig/XmlConfig and does not have a @Component annotation.

Comment: It worked now. It seems it was a mix of errors with the operators and the lack of ```@Component``` I you write it as an answer, I will give it as the correct one.

Comment: will do, and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `LoggingAspect` class is not picked up during component scanning as it is not explicitly declared in `JavaConfig`or `XmlConfig`, and does not have a `@Component` annotation (and [`@Aspect`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.11/org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect.html) annotations do not have this meta annotation themself).

Furthermore, the `@AfterThrowing` advice includes all named pointcuts using `&&` instead of `||`, stating that all the pointcuts must match (which is not possible considered they all refer to different packages).